# How to get storage information of the EFI partition?

Tags: windows, powershell

How can I get the size and current usage of the EFI partition on a disk?

I see that I can use the following command to at least the size of the partition, but I haven't found anything about how to get the current utilization:

`get-partition |Where-Object{ $_.GptType -eq "{c12a7328-f81f-11d2-ba4b-00a0c93ec93b}"} |Select Size`

Comment: Provided you're elevated, you can use `Get-Volume` to get these details. First use `Get-Partition` to get the partition's unique ID, then use `Get-Volume -UniqueId` to get `Size` and `SizeRemaining`. (On a modern system with no removable drives attached you can easily spot the volume because it'll likely be the only one formatted as FAT32 rather than NTFS, but counting on this is not reliable for automation.) Should you want to actually inspect the contents of the EFI partition, you can use `mountvol /s`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I gave it a try based on my understanding: `Get-Volume -UniqueId (get-partition |Where-Object{ $_.GptType -eq "{c12a7328-f81f-11d2-ba4b-00a0c93ec93b}"} |Select UniqueId)`, however that gives the following error `Get-Volume : No MSFT_Volume objects found with property 'UniqueId' equal to
'@{UniqueId={00000000-0000-0000-0000-100000000000}eui.00A0750126883708}'.`

Comment: You can't directly pipe that object into `UniqueId`, you need to specifically grab the `UniqueId` property so it's a string again. But actually it's more complicated; the `UniqueId` properties don't match (bit confusing there) and you need the `Guid` property, formatted differently. `Get-Volume -UniqueId "\\?\Volume$(((Get-Partition).Where{$_.GptType -eq '{c12a7328-f81f-11d2-ba4b-00a0c93ec93b}'}.Guid))\"` does it, although I think this is a needlessly cryptic one-liner and I'd probably split it up into multiple lines myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @JeroenMostert mentioned in the comments, this will work well:

```
Get-Volume -UniqueId "\\?\Volume$(((Get-Partition).Where{$_.GptType -eq '{c12a7328-f81f-11d2-ba4b-00a0c93ec93b}'}.Guid))\" | Select-Object Size, SizeRemaining
```

The GPT type is the GUID of the EFI partition on Windows, as seen [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table). This Unique ID is then passed into Get-Volume and will allow one to pull back the size & utilization information.